# Binding data to Dom is failing

Tags: php, angularjs, json

I am adding the response.data to $scope.studentData but still its not showing in DOM , before that I was getting angular.js:13550 Error: [ngRepeat:dupes], so I added track by $index which removed the error but still I cannot see the data in ng-repeat , also whenever I visit that partial template view , 2 Xhr call are to get the data from php I would be helpful if can help me removing those errors Thanks in advance , new is Angular please help.

```
app.controller("studentscontroller",function($scope,$http){
var st = [];
$http.get("php/studentdata.php")
.then(function(response){
//console.log(response.data);
$scope.studentData=response.data;
})
})

<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="student in studentData track by $index">
<td>{{student.id}}</td>
<td>{{student.name}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>


**php **
<?php

include("../php/dbconnect.php");
$datarcv = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = json_decode($datarcv);
//$id = $data->id;
$query = "select * from student ";
$exe =mysqli_query($link,$query);
$send=array();
$len = mysqli_num_rows($exe);
//echo $len;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($exe))
{
$send = array('id'=>$row['sid'],'name'=>$row['sname']);
}
echo json_encode($send);
?
}
```

Comment: Please start with readin [mcve] section.

Comment: we can't troubleshoot code we can't see. Post relevent code in question along with data sample from api

Comment: Sir mistakenly it was posted while i was typing can you see it now

Comment: You have php problems. Your `dupes` are likely from 500 server error output which is html string and not json. Verify in browser dev tools network for the actual request. Or even open that url directly in browser

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to use ng-repeat to show data but it doesn't appear on the view. 
The first,make sure that you are using the scope of the correct controller. to do that, try to show data on the view by `ng-bind="studentData"`. if ng-bind works, the problem comes from ng-repeat: to fix that problem, use $scope.**model**.studentData instead of $scope.studentData. If ng-bind still doesn't work, that mean you're using incorrect controller.

Answer (score 0):

A `GET` request has no body so there is no `file_get_contents("php://input")` and since you aren't validating it is likely you are getting an exception thrown trying to json_decode() it.

My guess is your error output is being returned and then passed into `ng-repeat` as nothing but a string...not an array as you expect.

Also, you are overwriting `$send` in every iteration of `while` and only sending one object representing the last row ...not an array of objects representing all rows.

Fix the array issue by changing :

```
$send = array('id'=>$row['sid'],'name'=>$row['sname']);
```

To

```
$send[] = array('id'=>$row['sid'],'name'=>$row['sname']);
```

Also you should be using your browser dev tools  to inspect what the server is actually sending you

Comment: Sir now I have changed as you mentioned yes I was missing those parenthesis , Thnak you but still i am failing to bind the data to the view .,I am getting object back but i am not getting anything in view

Comment: Thank you alot sir the problem is solved, i did changed the php but i missed changing the scope object in ng repeat , for which i was not getting data , it works fine now thank you one second,